# Union of 2 sets with beautiful soup select

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following html from a table with alternating light and dark rows:

```
<tr class="light">
    <td>....
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="dark">
    <td>....
```

I can get either all the light or all dark rows using:

```
soup.select('tr.light') or soup.select('tr.dark')
```

Is there a way to combine both in a single statement?

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful soup supports [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), so it should just allow you to use [grouping](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping).

If it does, then you could just select both via:

```
soup.select('tr.dark, tr.light')  # note the comma between.
```

**EDIT:** Beautiful soup seems to have rather limited CSS selector support, so alternatively you could try this:

```
import re
soup.find_all("td" class_=re.compile("light|dark"))
```

Another alternative is that [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is supposed to support the full range of CSS selectors.

Comment: Thanks, I'm upvoting you, but I was hoping to do this with select because I then need to continue to parse using the css selectors. I decided to do light = soup.select('tr.light') dark = soup.select('tr.dark') rows = light+dark - thank you - Bill